# Minimum events to call on a dynamic link

Tags: javascript, html, events

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dynamic Link</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" value="http://www.example.com/" id="input">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/" id="link">Linked text</a>
    <script>
        var link = document.getElementById('link'),
            input = document.getElementById('input');
        link.onclick = link.oncontextmenu = link.onmousedown = function () {
            this.href = input.value;
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/ca2DL/)

- `onclick`: called on the left click and keyboard focus +
  <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `oncontextmenu`: called on the right click and keyboard context menu
- `onmousedown`: called on the middle click in Firefox/IE and on the link drag to the address bar

Questions:

1. Are there any other ways to navigate to the URL of the link -- something I forgot to cover for perfect accessibility?
2. Can I reduce the number of events or do I have to use them all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'onblur' event for changing the href of the link.

```
var link = document.getElementById('link'),
input = document.getElementById('input');
input.onblur = function () {
    link.href = this.value;
};
```

Comment: Actually I already thought of `input.onchange`. But it has a problem: you call a function when it's not necessarily needed. What if the user leaves the `input` element to do something else and doesn't want to click on the link?

Comment: I said 'onblur' not 'onchange'. 'onblur' only fires when the user leaves the input (clicking away from input). So it is only fired when neccesary. When your focus is on the input, then you click on the link, the event fires and changes the href to the input.

Comment: "_onblur' only fires when the user leaves the input_" It has the same problem. What if the user leaves the input to click on a button or something like that?

Comment: Then it changes the link of the href to the value of the input. I don't see what you want to achieve....